# what is exactly firebase and is it best choice for authentication in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to know what is exactly firebase. When i want to create authentication for my app i see on google firebase is often used on flutter for do it but it is not clear what is it exactly. I have a MySQL/php api from the server side and i need to find a way for save on mobile phone an user id when the user create an account, what is the best solution for do that with security. I have seen too, there is people who uses shared preference but security is low i think

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a whole set of applications and services that acts as a link to Google Cloud, which provides these services. [Here's their website.](https://firebase.google.com/)

Firebase is a toolset that (according to them) allows you to “build, improve, and grow your app”, and they give you the tools that cover a large portion of the services that developers would normally have to build themselves. This includes things like analytics, authentication, databases, configuration, file storage, push messaging, etc.

This is different than traditional app development, which typically involves writing both frontend and backend software. The frontend code just invokes API endpoints exposed by the backend, and the backend code actually does the work. With firebase, your app accesses those services directly (or, allows you to write APIs to handle that, if needed)

[image: comparison]

These are the firebase functions that (arguably) are the most commonly used amongst developers.

- Authentication    — SECURE user login and identity, with applicable
  rules
- Realtime Database — realtime, cloud hosted, NoSQL database (older
  version)
- Cloud Firestore   — realtime, cloud hosted, NoSQL database (but with
  better queries)
- Cloud Storage     — massively scalable file storage
- Cloud Functions   — “serverless”, event driven backend (this is where
  you'd write your 
                   APIs)
- Firebase Hosting — global web hosting (this is GREAT for flutter
  because you can upload your designs immediately without paying for
  it.)
- ML Kit — SDK for common ML tasks

Here are all their services... but I haven't used most of them.
[image]

Finally, the great thing about firebase is that all their functionality is free, and you only start paying when the traffic starts growing.

Is it the best choice for authentication? **Without. a. doubt.**  Not only is it secure, it provides a wide range of side services like "login with your google/facebook/whatever account" and "Forgot your password" retrievals.  But it also allows for full token authentication, and access rules.

Sources: 
https://firebase.google.com/
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-firebase-the-complete-story-abridged-bcc730c5f2c0
https://howtofirebase.com/what-is-firebase-fcb8614ba442

Comment: Did this help at all?  Is there any additional information you need?

Answer (score 0):

as u have api already then what u can definitely use firebase for verifying the phone number of user & then continue him to register that way u can get verified phone number of user.

u dont have to save phone number of user u can get it using

`await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().phoneNumber`

what shared preference is used for is to store basic info about user like phone number, username, isLogin etc. but if u care about security which i dont think u need to worry about u can use another package like [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) which uses AES 256 CBC with PKCS7 padding encryption.

Comment: i need only store a user id on the phone. I have MySQL database for store all important information, i use api. Example if you need to save score in a game of one of your user you can't store it on the phone… You need to secure all and send it on external MySQL database. My game app will give money to users for the best score so i think all need to be on external MySQL database. I need only to have Something which is UNIQUE store on the phone and make the link with the MySQL database. What do you think about that ?

Comment: u mean like a token which then can be use to access that external database ? but u need to store all the basic information of the user in local storage if u r requesting all the time to db then good luck with the price